# sorting array of objects in node.js

Tags: arrays, node.js, sorting, facebook-graph-api

```
exports.getFbFriendsFromFbIdAndFbAccessTokenTest=function(id,token){

    var request = require('request');
    var urls = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + id + "/friends?access_token=" + token;

    request(urls, function(error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            var output = JSON.parse(body);          
            output.sort(function(a,b){
                if (a.name > b.name)
                  return 1;
                if (a.name < b.name)
                  return -1;
                  // a must be equal to b
                return 0;
             });                

            console.log(output);            
        }           
    });
```

}

I want to sort the facebook friend's list in ascending order. Currently i am getting the following result in console:

```
`{ data: `
```

`[ { name: 'xxx', id: '547dsad1' },`
     `{ name: 'xxx', id: '55324iii' },`
     `{ name: 'xxx', id: '55yyy' },`
........
........

But it gives error that object output has no property sort.
I have also used Array.prototype:

```
Array.prototype.sortByProp = function(p){
return this.sort(function(a,b){
return (a[p] > b[p]) ? 1 : (a[p] < b[p]) ? -1 : 0;
});
}

output.sortByProp('name');
```

But then it shows the same error that object output has not property sortByProp.
Is there any other way to solve this problem?

Comment: are you sure `output` is 100% an array and not an object `Array.isArray(obj)`

Comment: Have you tried logging `output = JSON.parse(body)` to console to see what you're actually working with? It looks like the variable you're trying to "sort" isn't an array. (edit: looks like dark_ruby beat me to it)

Answer (score 3):

`output` is an object, `output.data` is an array

```
Array.prototype.sortByProp = function(p){
  return this.sort(function(a,b){
    return (a[p] > b[p]) ? 1 : (a[p] < b[p]) ? -1 : 0;
  });
};

console.log(output.data.sortByProp('name'));
```

Comment: Its not giving any result in the console.

Comment: it will not, to get result into `console` you need to `console.log` it, I updated my answer

Comment: TypeError: Object [object Object],[object Object].....[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object] has no method 'sortByProp'

Comment: can you run `Array.isArray` on an object you are trying to run `sortByProp`on, just to make sure it is an array?

Comment: It is returning false.

Comment: can you paste your entire JSON that comes back from service, we'll likely need to convert object to array

Comment: { data: 
   [ { name: 'Ranjan Dhingra', id: '547467021' },
     { name: 'Pulkit Garg', id: '553244245' },
     ...
     { name: 'Mandeep Kaur Sidhu', id: '100005914231176' },
     { name: 'Ritesh Sankhala', id: '100007033209997' } ],
  paging: { next: 'https://graph.facebook.com/100.......47/friends?access_token=CAACEdEose.....N7ya3p3naiHS0i8oOQk6ag6aIIrnYezhvxA8qltkC1Y09LkMBzwQs1ZBZAV1ghZCRA8JVfWuLQqcZCQTGc37VlZAsZCzU2MHmjsTu99h8d6GJCZAZATyvyZAUHbeWQKwr9cMM44ztvDXVZAbhopoOTGJn0bWv4ZAqkOn1uFOEfxILx1q0tmpx6ZApfzZATNZBF4cAZDZD&limit=5000&offset=5000&__after_id=100007033209997' } }

Comment: if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                var output =JSON.parse(body);   
    console.log(output);